# Map Matching? (Finding Nearest Roads...)

Tags: openlayers-2, cartography, network, arcgis-desktop

I am making Pedestrian Navigation System for my school

I created node and arc and digitized buildings with ArcGIS. Then, exported KML to use Javascript Dijkstra's Algorithm to find route.

So far, so good.
The thing is if i want to find the shortest path or fastest route, I have to type NODE number.

I want a person to click (or tab his or her's smartphone screen) a building and automatically snap the point to the nearest nodes (roads)

What keyword should i look up or do you have any idea?

Comment: You said you used ArcGIS (for Desktop) to create and edit your vector data but are you using ArcGIS for Server (and Mobile) for any of the other components?

Comment: oh shoot sorry. I do this on Open Layers..